# Is there a way to have an if statement return the information of a cell?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am making a camera check in/check out system. I have the person fill out a google form that is linked to a google sheet. This gives me what camera they checked out, their name, and the time checked out. I have another sheet that shows all of the data sorted. So, the camera if it checked in or out and the time it is checked out. Now I need to put the name next to the person that checked out the camera.

The way I have it set up you can check out multiple cameras at once so a simple `LOOKUP` won't work. I am trying to make an IF statement that looks at the date and time the camera was checked out and then goes into the google form linked sheet and looks for the date and time that is the same and then pastes the name, which is in the cell next to the date and time, in to the cell next to the camera in my other sheet.

This is what I have so far:

```
=IF(E2 = Data_Entered!A2:A, ,"Highlands")
```

I have it say Highlands if it is checked in Because the way I made the date was:

```
= If(C2= "Check Out", Now(), "Highlands")
```

So I don't need the name of the person when they check it in.

I want the IF statement to be like:

```
=IF(E2 = Data_Entered!A2:A,PASTE,"Highlands")
```

or something like that. As long as it works!

This is a link to a copy of the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YbtxgI-Wp9nikDpKrLrpehNvQP3nRjNAWGPv2tMc5zg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YbtxgI-Wp9nikDpKrLrpehNvQP3nRjNAWGPv2tMc5zg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete everything in **D:E** range and paste this in **D2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), IF(C2:C= "Check Out", VLOOKUP(A2:A&"♦"&C2:C, 
 SORT(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF((Data_Entered!E2:I<>"")*(Data_Entered!B2:B="Check Out"), 
 "♠"&Data_Entered!E2:I&"♦"&Data_Entered!B2:B&
 "♣"&Data_Entered!D2:D&"♣"&Data_Entered!A2:A, ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99)),"♠")), "♣"), 1, 0, 3, 0), {2, 3}, 0), "Highlands"), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: When I use the code it gives me the name of the first person who checks out the camera. If someone checks out the camera later it gives you the name of the first person who checked out the camera.

Comment: Thankyou so much!

Comment: I have been using the program and it has been working well but, the timestamp is weird: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O_khxLQU9FS9Hrh8E7ZDH4TXXIFWu-DRQ1pnUL8_IJI/edit?usp=sharing